# (MS EXCEL) How do I replace cells with formulas to its calculated value AUTOMATICALLY?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am making a payroll program in Excel and one of my concerns is that the salaries of the employees are searched using the INDEX and MATCH or VLOOKUP function. The problem is if the salaries get updated in the future (e.g. a raise or changes in rates), all the previous entries that used the old salaries will be updated to the new salaries. This is a disaster and would make my entire program useless and inefficient. Therefore I need to automatically lock previous calculated cells after a certain time.

Edit: Note we do not want to do this manually such as copy pasting values only because almost all cells are connected to each other and one mistake by the encoder or if they forget to do this before updating a value, everything will be messed up.

Comment: Copy and paste as values

Comment: Was hoping for some function or other method instead of the "manual" way. I hope that was not too complicated to understand

Comment: If you want a VBA solution show us what code you already have and where that needs improving. We are not a free code writing service.

Comment: Couldn't find anything in google was hoping to get some leads here. I don't know the VBA language and I am not sure if it is possible. I do not need free code I just need "expert" guidance on how to approach it

Comment: this can be achieved easily, the only problem is "after a certain time", you will need to trace changes and save some kind of timestamp somewhere

Comment: start from recording a macro with copying -> pasting as values and try to modify the code

Comment: Yeah I believe the "after a certain time" portion is simple. It's the function that will run after that condition is met is what i'm troubled about. I'll see what I can do from macros thanks

Comment: Copy and paste special is something vba does just fine

Comment: Then I can start learning on VBA as well. Thanks

Comment: As mentioned used "After a certain time", or as I prefer to call it "Effective Date".  It will be one extra column in in your table of employee salary information.  One you have that you can add another search condition to your formula which will vary depending on how its set up.  in match and Vlookup you want to look at that last option argument that you can set to 1 or 0 (or -1) depending on the function used.  You do not want an exact match on effective date, but rather and after a date, or before date.   Again all depends on how you have things set up and how your are doing your search.

Answer (score 0):

No! Not copying and pasting, there's a simpler way. You want to convert the Formula property of a given cell (what's shown in the formula bar in Excel) into the Value property of the cell (what's shown in the cell on the spreadsheet). For a given range A1:B6 this would done by the statement

```
 Range("A1:B6").formula = Range("A1:B6").value
```

But there's a quirk in Excel that you can run faster by accessing a Value2 property, so

```
 Range("A1:B6").formula = Range("A1:B6").value2
```

The rest of the code is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: Thank you will try this out